# Changes in Web.xml not applied to Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, authentication, server, web.xml

I am quite new to Tomcat and trying to get my head around user authentication.

I added `BASIC` authentication to my `web.xml`, which worked fine.

Now, I have my own user authentication form on the website and want to remove the Tomcat authentication. So, I put the whole security section in my `web.xml` in comments. Unfortunately, nothing has changed after that edit to `web.xml`: The user is still asked for their username and password.

I reverted these changes and changed the password in my `tomcat-users.xml`. No change in behavior there as well: I can't login with the new password; I still have to use the old one.

I restarted Tomcat each time I made a change. If I randomly change stuff in my `web.xml` the site crashes, so there is *some* effect if I change certain things.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Which `web.xml` were you editing: Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` or your application's `WEB-INF/web.xml`?

Comment: I am editing the web.xml of tomcat.

Comment: You should stop that. Remove every change you ever made to `conf/web.xml` and instead modify the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file within your application.